# Permutations and partial orders

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, ordered-fields

Consider the set of all permutations of $n$ numbers $\mathfrak{S}(n)$. Each permutation can be seen as a total ordering relation of $n$ elements $a_1,...,a_n$, such that
\begin{equation}
a_{\pi(1)}<a_{\pi(2)}<...<a_{\pi(n)}.
\end{equation}
Specific subsets of the set of permutations can be used instead to identify partial orderings. For example, for $n=3$, the three permutations $S=\{\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3\}\subset \mathfrak{S}(3)$ defined by
\begin{align}
\pi_1(1)=1, \  \pi_1(2)=2, \  \pi_1(3)=3, \\ 
\pi_2(1)=2, \  \pi_2(2)=1, \  \pi_2(3)=3, \\ 
\pi_3(1)=2, \  \pi_3(2)=3, \  \pi_3(3)=1,   
\end{align}
identify the orderings
\begin{align}
a_1<a_2<a_3, \ a_2<a_1<a_3, \ a_2<a_3<a_1. 
\end{align}
which are equivalent, when taken together, to the partial ordering
\begin{equation}
a_2<a_3.
\end{equation}
Another example is given by the two total orderings
\begin{equation}
a_1<a_2<a_3, \ a_2<a_1<a_3, 
\end{equation}
which correspond to the partial ordering
\begin{equation}
a_1<a_3, \ a_2<a_3.
\end{equation}

Any other subset of permutations, $S\subseteq \mathfrak{S}(n)$ can be certainly be divided into disjoint unions of sets $S_1,...,S_n$ such that $S_i$ corresponds to a partial order (the trivial decomposition is $S=\{\pi_1,...,\pi_m\}$ and $S_i=\{\pi_i\}$ $i=1,...,m$, in which case each sets corresponds to a total order).

My question is the following: is there a way to decompose $S$ into a minimal number of sets $S_1,...,S_n$ corresponding to partial orderings (minimal with respect to $n$), and is there a unique way to achieve this decomposition? According to this decomposition, the set of all permutations $\mathfrak{S}(n)$ corresponds to the partial ordering in which no element is actually in any ordered relation with any other element. If represented as a graph, it would have nodes but no links.

Comment: If I understand correctly, given a set of total orderings, you are searching for a minimum collection of posets such that the set of total orderings extending at least one of the posets is equal to your set of total orderings.

Comment: Hi! That's an interesting way to formulate the question. It is clear that if you take the union of the extensions of all possible posets in the collection you obtain the original set of total orderings. The "at least one" part confuses me a bit. Since the partial orderings are incompatible one with the other, I would expect the "at least one" to be substituted with "all".

Comment: If I understand correctly, if we take the set of total orderings $\{123, 132, 213, 312\}$, it can be represented by the posets $p1 = \{x_1 \prec x_2\}$ and $p_2 = \{x_1 \prec x_3\}$. $123$ extends both $p_1$ and $p_2$, but $213$ only extends $p_2$. However, $231$ extends neither $p_1$ nor $p_2$.

Comment: If my interpretation is correct, then this is equivalent to minimizing a DNF where the literals are of the form $a\prec b$. I have a hunch that it is NP-hard, since minimizing DNF over a boolean formula is NP-hard.